# convert shell output to html table

Tags: javascript, php, shell

I am using php for executing server commands for retrieving logs data from server, simply executed the command in php using following syntax.

```
<?php
    $result = shell_exec("$cmd");
    echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
?>
```

Above query returns the output in unstructured table format, I need to convert it into structured HTML table and display on webpage.

I had saved the above command output in CSV file and used following javascript function to format result in HTML table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('path/upload.csv', function(data) {
    var build = '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">\n';
    //var rows = data.split("\n");
    //rows.forEach( function getvalues(thisRow) {
    var head = data.split("\n");
    for(var i=2;i<3;i++){
    build += "<tr><th>" + head[i].replace("first seen", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;seen") + "</th></tr>";
    //build += "<tr>";
            //var col = data.split("\n");   
            for(var i=3;i<head.length;i++){
            build += "<tr><td>" + head[i].split("\n") + "</td></tr>";
            }               
    }
    build += "</table>";
        $('#wrap').append(build);   
    });
</script>
```

above script return result in rows format, I need to split it into columns

[image: my needs]

Comment: well, show us the data you need to structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need parse eacho row of data and add proper html table's tags.